# rmarkdown knitting error cannot replicate NULL to a non-zero length

Tags: r-markdown

I have a rmarkdown which loops to render a list of other rmarkdowns:

````
```{r}
for(i in 0:22){
   save(i, file = "/path/to/i.RData")
   rmarkdown::render("path/to/secondRmarkdown.Rmd", output_file = paste0("/path/to/Results/Report_", i, ".html"))
}
```
````

Previous to this chunk, I have a pretty similar chunk in the same rmarkdown, and it loops without a problem while knitting the main one. Moreover, when I run the chunk manually, it also loops.

However, when knitting, this specific chunk gives the following error after rendering only the first rmarkdown file for i=0 (which succeeds):

```
# Error in rep_len(label, length(meta): cannot replicate NULL to a non-zero length
```

I modified the *secondRmarkdown.Rmd* to a simple file to make sure it wasn't something from it:

````
```{r}    
load(file = "/path/to/i.RData")
print(i)
```
````

I have Ubuntu 5.13.0-40. R version 4.2.0, Rstudio version 2022.02.2, rmarkdown version 2.14

Any idea? TIA!

Comment: Obvious for some; not obvious for others (I know it and still screw it up sometimes).  Have you made sure any path references in the RMD are documented as the location of the RMD as the 'working directory' of the RMD? Perhaps, not literally, but for all intents and purposes, that's essentially what happens. Whereas, for an R file, the current working directory is exactly whatever you set it to.

Comment: Hi @Kat, I actually have tried. Setting wd both in the chunk where I'm looping and in the looped rmarkdown. Still rendering only the first element of the series :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out: it's a cache problem.

To solve it, either setting cache to FALSE:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
      cache = FALSE)
```

Or in case of wanting to keep cache, disabling cache.lazy:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  cache = TRUE,
  cache.lazy = FALSE)
```